# How to fill with an another color of an intersecting area of two circles?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the below picture but I don't understand how to fill it with another colour.

[image]

Here's my code:

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<style>
  body {
    background:#09042A;
  }
.a {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #7B3F61;
    margin-left:4.2em; 
  margin-top:4.67em;
    position:relative;
  }
  .b {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #E78481;
    margin-left:10.4em; 
  margin-top:-9.44em;    
  }
</style>
```

Comment: From CSS Battle

Answer (score 3):

Try like this.
You can change mix-blend-mode

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  body {
    background:#fffff;
  }
.a {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #7B3F61;
    margin-left:4.2em; 
    margin-top:4.67em;
    position:relative;
  }
  .b {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #E78481;
    margin-left:10.4em; 
    margin-top:-9.44em;    
  }


.b {
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, I got it but here's another problem occurred that is the colour, so how I am going to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

can be done with only background:

```css
.box {
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  --i: 74px, #0000 75px;
  background: 
     radial-gradient(circle at 250px 50%, #09042A var(--i))  0 0/200px no-repeat, 
     radial-gradient(circle at -50px 50%, #09042A var(--i)) 100% 0/200px no-repeat, 
     radial-gradient(circle, #7B3F61 var(--i)) -50px, 
     radial-gradient(circle, #E78481 var(--i)) 50px #09042A;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```